# React router issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hi i have problems getting routes work.

Here is my route.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from './Home';
import Add from './Add';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
       export default (


<Router  history={browserHistory}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
      <Route path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route path='/add/' component={Add} />
      </Router>
      );
```

Here is App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import routes from './route';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }


  render() {
    return (
<Router history={hashHistory}>{routes}</Router>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is Add.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Views/Header';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router'


import './styles/App.css';
import './styles/layout.css';

class Add extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    render() {
        return (
      <div className=" ">
       <Header />
            <h2> Add a cake </h2>
      </div>
            );
    }
}

export default Add;
```

I haven't added Home.js because Home works just fine.

but when i click  '/add' url points to 'http://localhost:3000/add#/'  but nothing happens.

can you please help.

Thanks

Comment: What's the `#` in front doing?  I guess you're using `BrowserHistory` right?

Comment: @Rowland not sure what you mean. if you are talking about 'http://localhost:3000/add#/' that's  not what i set - it is what url pane points to when i click '/add' -yes i am using BrowserHistory

Comment: Can you remove the extra `/` here `<Route path='/add/' component={Add} />`?

Comment: even if i change to   <Route path='/add' component={Add} /> it didn't help.

Comment: Can you verify the version of react-router you're using? I think you need [react-router-dom](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-dom) if you're running v4 and I doubt `IndexRoute` is not deprecated in V4

Comment: i am using react-router 3

Comment: I see you using hashHistory and not browserHistory, how exactly are you navigating to add

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri please look at my route.js where i am using Browserhistory - what do you think?

Comment: I changed my other place where i was using hashHistory to browserHistory and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using a Router within a Router in App.js, one with hashHistory and the other with browserHistory.

Change your Routes to

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from './Home';
import Add from './Add';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
export default (
    <Router  history={browserHistory}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        <Route path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/add' component={Add} />
      </Router>
      );
```

and app.js to

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import routes from './route';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }


  render() {
    return (
         <div>{routes}</div>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```